# Symbolic block matrix calculation in Maple

Tags: linear-algebra, maple

In Maple,

```
restart; with(LinearAlgebra);
E := Matrix([[A, B]]);
E. Transpose(E);
```

yields

```
A^2 + B^2
```

However, I would like that Maple treat A and B as block matrices and yield

```
A.Transpose(A) + B.Transpose(B)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Maple `assume()` command for this ([link](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=assume)). Scroll down that link, or ctrl-f and find the part where they show how to assume that a variable is a "SquareMatrix" type. Basically, Maple is treating your variables like they are real numbers, and you need to tell it not to do that. Once you get the assume statement right, it should print out the matrix-based solution.

If you get a lot of crufty extra symbols, this might be because Maple usually flags variables for which the `assume()` function was used (so the user remembers they are making an assumption about that variable). For example, it often replaces `a` with `~a` if you issue an `assume()` regarding `a`. You can turn this off with the command `interface(showassumed=0)`.

Comment: I tried your solution idea but I end up with the same problem as in the question. Looking at about(A) and about(B) Maple told me that both have the SquareMatrix assumption but if I use Transpose(E) the transpose is not added to A or B.